# "Rules" vs. "principles"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns

What's the difference between *rules* and *principles*? For example, which one is the better fit in the following context?

> Strict *_*_ govern the clothes we wear.

Comment: I would use rules because of the "strict rules", but without strict, I  think you can use either - [Google NGRAM](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strict+rules%2Cstrict+principles%2Crules+govern%2Cprinciples+govern&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: *Principles* can only be 'principles,' there can be no 'strict principles.'

Comment: NB: Although the nominated duplicate has since been cleared up and is visible only to users with the requisite privilege (rep 10k+), the answers here are better, and this question would still be closed now for lack of obvious research.

Answer (score 3):

A principle is a sort of rule, but more to govern personal behaviour. Think of it as a personal rule, one that shouldn't affect other people. A rule is generally imposed by a figure of authority, and used to guide and govern people. So in the above sentence, it would be:

> Strict **rules** govern the clothes we wear

Because it is being imposed by someone else. If someone were to say:

> That goes against my principles.

That would mean that they felt you were breaking one of their personal rules, or perhaps asking them to break a personal rule.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Rules state what is legally or procedurally correct, whereas principles state what is morally or intrinsically correct.

To address your specific example,

> Strict *rules* govern the clothes we wear

because "strict" and "govern" both imply that an dress code is being enforced, or some fashion conventions should be adhered to (e.g., "Don't wear white after Labor Day" or "Don't wear fur or leather to a courtroom").

In contrast, you might say,

> Her *principles* forbid her from wearing fur or leather

The difference there is that the restriction is self imposed.

Comment: Hm... I would think so, as well. However, one can be strict with oneself in the matter of principles, too -- some are, some may not be.

Comment: @Kris But you wouldn't use the word *govern* when talking about self-discipline.